# Trying to add text file information to an Array List

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I am working on a project where I have to build a course organizer that can load courses from a file. I am having a little bit of trouble with getting the file loaded into the program, and the information in the file put into the array. The information in the file is just course information that can also be inputted in the program itself. My hopes are to have to program be able to both read and write information to the same file. Any tips as to what I am doing wrong? I am not very experienced with reading/writing in java. Any help is appreciated greatly.

Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
 C:\java\bin>javac CourseOrganizer.java
CourseOrganizer.java:248: missing method body, or declare abstract
    private static void LoadCourses();
                        ^
CourseOrganizer.java:253: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class ListCourses
location: class CourseOrganizer
                ListCourses lines = new ArrayList(ListCourses);
                ^
2 errors
```

And here is the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CourseOrganizer
{
    static ArrayList ListCourses = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStreamReader inp = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        int nOption  = 0;
        try
        {
            inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            input = new BufferedReader(inp);
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("1. Add Courses");
                System.out.println("2. Modify Courses");
                System.out.println("3. Delete Courses");
                System.out.println("4. Sort Courses");
                System.out.println("5. Show all Courses");
                System.out.println("6. Load Courses");
                System.out.println("7. Exit.");
                System.out.println("\nChoose an option(1-6) >> ");
                nOption = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

                switch(nOption)
                {
                    case 1:
                        AddCourses(input);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ModifyCourses(input);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        DeleteCourses(input);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        SortCourses(input);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        ShowAllCourses();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        System.out.println("Exiting program. Press any key to continue....");
                        input.read();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }
    //Setup Add Courses function for case 1
    private static void AddCourses(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        CourseTemplate tmpObject = null;
        while(true)
        {
            tmpObject = new CourseTemplate();
            System.out.println("Course Name >> ");
            tmpObject.CourseName = input.readLine().toString();
            System.out.println("Day of Course "+tmpObject.CourseName+"(1...6) >> ");
            tmpObject.Day = input.readLine().toString();
            System.out.println("Time of Course Start "+tmpObject.CourseName+" (in HH:MM AM/PM format)  >> ");
            tmpObject.Time = input.readLine().toString();
            System.out.println("Course Mark "+tmpObject.CourseName+"(0...100) >>");
            tmpObject.Mark = input.readLine().toString();
            if(tmpObject != null)
                ListCourses.add(tmpObject);

            System.out.println("\n Do you want to add another Course?(y/n) >>");            
            if(!input.readLine().toLowerCase().equals("y"))
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void ModifyCourses(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
         CourseTemplate tmpObject = null;
         System.out.println("Name of the Course to modify >> ");
         String OldCourseName = input.readLine();
         int index = getCourseIndexByName(OldCourseName);
         if(index == -1)
         {
             System.out.println(" Course " + OldCourseName+ " not found.");
         }
         else
         {
             tmpObject = (CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(index);
             showCourse(tmpObject);
             System.out.println("What you want to modify (Name|Day|Time|Mark)? >>");
             String strOption = input.readLine();
             if("name".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
             {
                System.out.println("New Name of the Course >> ");
                tmpObject.CourseName = input.readLine().toString();
             }
             else  if("day".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
             {
                System.out.println("New Day of the Course "+tmpObject.CourseName+"(1...6) >> ");
                tmpObject.Day = input.readLine().toString();
             }
             else  if("mark".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
             {
                System.out.println("New Mark of the Course "+tmpObject.CourseName+"(0...100) >> ");
                tmpObject.Day = input.readLine().toString();
             }
             else if("time".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
             {
                System.out.println("New Time of the Course "+tmpObject.CourseName+" (in HH:MM AM/PM format)  >> ");
                tmpObject.Time = input.readLine().toString();
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Unable to locate the propety entered..");
             }

             ListCourses.set(index, tmpObject);
         }
    }

    private static int getCourseIndexByName(String Name)
    {
        int index = -1;
        CourseTemplate tmp =null;
        for(int i=0;i<ListCourses.size();i++)
        {
            tmp = (CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i);
            if(tmp.CourseName.toLowerCase().equals(Name.toLowerCase()))
            {    
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static void showCourse(CourseTemplate tcourse)
    {
        System.out.println(tcourse.CourseName+"\t\t"+tcourse.Day+"\t"+tcourse.Time+"\t"+tcourse.Mark);
    }

    private static void DeleteCourses(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
         System.out.println("Name of the Course to delete >> ");
         String OldCourseName = input.readLine();
         int index = getCourseIndexByName(OldCourseName);
         if(index == -1)
         {
             System.out.println(" Course " + OldCourseName+ " not found.");
         }
         else
         {
             ListCourses.remove(index);
             System.out.println(" Course " + OldCourseName+ "deleted successfully.");
         }
    }

    private static void SortCourses(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
         System.out.println("Enter the key to sort (Name|Day|Time|Mark)? >>");
         String strOption = input.readLine();
         int nSize = ListCourses.size();
         String str1, str2;
         if("name".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
         {
             for(int i = 0;i<nSize;i++)
             {
                 for(int j = (i+1);j<nSize;j++)
                 {
                     str1 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i)).CourseName;
                     str2 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(j)).CourseName;

                     if(str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2) > 0)
                     {
                         CourseTemplate  tmp = (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(i);
                         ListCourses.set(i, (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(j));
                         ListCourses.set(j, tmp);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else  if("day".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
         {
             for(int i = 0;i<nSize;i++)
             {
                 for(int j = (i+1);j<nSize;j++)
                 {
                     str1 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i)).Day;
                     str2 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(j)).Day;

                     if(str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2) > 0)
                     {   
                         CourseTemplate  tmp = (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(i);
                         ListCourses.set(i, (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(j));
                         ListCourses.set(j, tmp);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else if("time".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
         {
             for(int i = 0;i<nSize;i++)
             {
                 for(int j = (i+1);j<nSize;j++)
                 {
                     str1 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i)).Time;
                     str2 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(j)).Time;

                     if(str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2) > 0)
                     {
                         CourseTemplate  tmp = (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(i);
                         ListCourses.set(i, (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(j));
                         ListCourses.set(j, tmp);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else if("mark".equals(strOption.toLowerCase()))
         {
             for(int i = 0;i<nSize;i++)
             {
                 for(int j = (i+1);j<nSize;j++)
                 {
                     str1 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i)).Mark;
                     str2 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(j)).Mark;

                     if(str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2) > 0)
                     {
                         CourseTemplate  tmp = (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(i);
                         ListCourses.set(i, (CourseTemplate) ListCourses.get(j));
                         ListCourses.set(j, tmp);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Unable to locate the text entered..");
         }
         ShowAllCourses();
    }

    private static void LoadCourses();

        public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Courses.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            ListCourses lines = new ArrayList();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
        }

    private static void ShowAllCourses()
    {
         System.out.println("Course List\n");
         System.out.println("Name\t\tDay\tTime\tMark");
         for(int i=0;i<ListCourses.size();i++)
         {

             showCourse((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i));
         }
    }
}
class CourseTemplate
{
    public String CourseName = "";
    public String Day = "";
    public String Time="";
    public String Mark="";
}
```

Comment: Way down in the code you have the following: `ListCourses lines = new ArrayList();`. Maybe I missed it, but most other places you try to cast a line (a String) to `CourseTemplate` by doing the following all over the place: `str1 = ((CourseTemplate)ListCourses.get(i)).Mark;`

I haven't seen the text file, but it seems that this cast of string-to-object won't work. Does this code actually work? Is this homework?

Comment: It will help a great deal if you use Java naming conventions: class names should start with an upper case letter and variable names should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: If I take out the whole section for loading the text file, the code works. As soon as I try to put in load file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

```
static ArrayList ListCourses = new ArrayList();
```

So ***ListCources*** is actually the name of your **ArrayList** object.
Now in your **readLines** method, you have:

```
ListCourses lines = new ArrayList();
```

Which does not make sense since *ListCources* is a variable name not an object type. In order to correct this, the above line must be changed to:

```
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
```

Hence your method will look like this:

```
public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Courses.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
        }
```

And may I suggest to declare your **ArrayList** with a specific type. This will help the compiler to pinpoint future problems and is generally a better practice.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**EDIT:**
Also before the ***readLines()*** method, you've declared:

```
private static void LoadCourses();
```

This method does not have a body hence the compiler will complain. If you don't need it , remove it or implement it.

Comment: now I am getting this:
C:\java\bin>javac CourseOrganizer.java
CourseOrganizer.java:248: missing method body, or declare abstract
    private static void LoadCourses();
                        ^
CourseOrganizer.java:259: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object[]
required: java.lang.String[]
            return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
                                ^
2 errors

Comment: And now I just get "illegal start of expression" on line 253 "public String[]..."

Comment: @user1965245, read my "Edit". In order to resolve this java.lang.Object[] required: java.lang.String[] return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]); follow my solution. Change ListCourses lines to ArrayList lines.

Answer (score 0):

hei friend,I have not seen u saved the course info in the list to the disk,u never use an OutPutStream or BufferedWriter,so there is no text file,and how can u read the Courses.txt by FileReader?(u shall create and save it in the first)...  Secondly,I see, in the switch struct,the "case 6" is different from your screen message which is for user to choise,is it?